# Race condition naming EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, race-condition

We are having a race condition issue while generating names for our auto-scaled EC2 instances.

For each instance in a specific autoscaling group, we want to set the Name tag on that instance (and add a dns entry in Route53) that matches a well recognized pattern.  E.G. *server1.example.com*, *server2.example.com*, etc.

Our auto scaling group is configured with an image that executes a Ruby script at startup.  Using the [Ruby AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html), this Ruby script:

- pulls the existing instance tags for the specific domain name.
- Uses that information to determine the next instance name.

For example, if it finds *server1.example.com* and *server2.example.com*, it would set it's own tag/dns entry to be *server3.example.com*

The problem is a classic race condition.  If the instances come up within a certain time window of each other, we get duplicate names.  For example, if the autoscaling group is configured to have zero instances and I change this to force the group to have 3 instances, most of the time I will end up with one instance tagged with *server1.example.com* and two with *server2.example.com*.

With a transactional database, we would solve this problem by locking the row we are changing.  If this were a variable in a multi-threaded program, we would also put some kind of lock around the shared data.  But here we are using the EC2 tag database and I've found nothing in my research suggesting we can lock a specific tag in an account while changes are made.

The only practical solution I've come up with is to create a separate database to store these tag values.  Since an RDS Mysql instance does support row locking, this would work.  But creating a database just for this purpose feels like overkill.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Isn't a more practical solution to not reply on the instances themselves to name themselves?

Comment: I would consider naming servers this way as an anti-pattern for ASGs to start with. However, since you already mentioned distributed locking approach: DynamoDB can provide you with atomic (conditional) writes functionality without extra RDS setup, just create a table and query it from AWS CLI or AWS Ruby SDK. Maybe something to consider if you want to pursue your approach?
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/put-item.html

Comment: Why do you wish to assign a name to ephemeral instances? If you just need a unique name, use the `InstanceId`, which is guaranteed unique, eg `i-xxxx.example.com`.